# CodeIgniter Help

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to build an autosuggest using CodeIgniter, can i have some examples?

Comment: Closing: Not a Real Question.

Comment: This website works on the fact that people have a problem, have started a solution and have either reached a dead-on and is looking for opinions on how to resolve the problem. Its not an *ask and you shall receive website*

Answer (score 0):

Try their [video tutorials.](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/) They show you how to make a [blog](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/blog/) and a [basic introduction to CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/intro/).

Also, they have another [list of tutorials](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category:Help::Tutorials) that might give you a better idea.

Comment: your stuff is outdates, plz improve.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PHP form_helper that shows you how to add javascript events and PHP callbacks on to form elements both of these you will need to use to work.

Good Luck